# Javascript error: "Expected ';' " when declaring a Date variable

Tags: javascript

```
function validateDate(){
    Date now = new Date(); //error here
 }
```

I get and error saying expected ';' when ever I declare that line `Date now =....`

Anyone know why?

Comment: Which Javascript book are you learning from? This is not Javascript syntax. Looks more like Java.

Comment: What do you expect "Date now" to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is weakly-typed; all variable declarations start with the keyword `var`:

```
var now = new Date();
```

Comment: [`Let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is also an option, but this will likely break on older browsers, if this is a concern.